# Node.js using Vash view engine: how to pass vash model to angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

In Shawn Wildermuth's Pluralsight course "Node.js for .NET Developers", he demonstrated how to embed angular in vash view. Basically:

```
@html.extend('layout', function(model){

  @html.block("body", function(model) {

<div ng-app="app">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="homeCtrl">
            <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

  })
})
```

My question is how can I pass the data from vash model into angular controller?

In Shawn's demo, he is fetching the data in controller independently.

If the data is already supplied in the vash view model, how can I pass it over to angular so that it doesn't have to make another trip to server? I tried to use ngInit, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

Shawn responded to you question on Pluralsight. Unfortunately, his solution didn't work for me. But I was able to do what you are trying to do using this workaround:

First define a hidden field inside your view:

```
<input value="@model.yourData" name="someName" type="hidden" id="dataFromServer">
```

Then in your controller, access the data by just fetching the hidden element.

```
$scope.serverData = document.getElementById("dataFromServer").value;
```